SendMail and Azure
I have an Ubuntu Linux VM hosted in Azure. I installed SendMail and configured it to use port 587 using this guide. https://bobcares.com/blog/linux-sendmail-port-587/
I understand that port 25 is blocked in Azure, and you must use 587, which requires authentication. I'm new to using SendMail, and I cannot find any decent guides on how to send test emails with an authenticated mailbox.
Please, could someone provide me with the details on how to do this or point me in the right direction?
Thank you

I think I've figured it out. It looks like SendMail doesn't have any authentication options, so I must use an alternative method.
I found that ssmtp https://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp allows you to authenticate.
I can install it using
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ssmtp

open the config file
sudo nano /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

setup the configuration
root=email@domain.com
mailhub=smtp.office365.com:587
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=email@domain.com
AuthPass=ENTER PASSWORD HERE
UseTLS=YES

Test email using
echo "Test Email" | ssmtp email@domain.com
or printf "Subject: Test Email" | ssmtp email@domain.com

